# Drawing to FrameBuffer ignores depth test

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer, depth-buffer

I'm drawing my scene to a texture using FBO and reading the pixel in order to select my object.

The problem is that the drawing into the texture is ignoring the depth [image: Left is real scene and right is the texture]

On Left is scene and right is the texture (saved it to file for debug reasons).
As u can see there are 2 planes one on top of another and the one in the front is more directed up. although on the texture it's the other way around. and this makes the user pick the plane in the background when he sees the other plane.

I'v tried to enable everything i thought of but i guess i'm missing something.

Comment: does the FBO have a depth buffer? if not there is no depth to test against

Comment: Also make sure to enable depth test `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` and depth write `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)`.

Comment: I've tried it also. But still same i'm getting the same results.

Comment: ratchet freak- How do i do that ? What i'm doing today is creating a texture and then frame buffer - `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uintFBTex, 0);`. Can I add to the same texture the depth buffer ?

Comment: Solved it by creating a render buffer for the depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ratchet freak,

I've realized that i skipped the depth buffer :)

I just had to create a render buffer for the depth component and attach it to the frame buffer object.